# implement dll in .EXE

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a problem with a nugget package and the .dll used by this.

I've added the NFC-ACR122U Nugget package from Sydesoft to my c# .Net app.

The Nugget than has two dll coming with it.

When i now distribute the .exe file to other computers, the .exe will not be able to start because it's not finding the .dll. When i place the dll in the same directory as the exe, it's working again.

But is there a way do include the dll in the exe, so that the dll just come with the exe when i distribute it?

Comment: "When i now distribute the .exe file to other computers, the .exe will not be able to start because it's not finding the .dll" - unless you are are specifically doing a single-file deployment, *that's not how you deploy an application*; what framework are you targeting? perhaps what you are after is simply "single file deployment": https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview

Comment: ^^ The other option would be to create an [installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022), that will include the .dlls in the deployment.

Comment: You can link dll dependencies into exe files as resources and load them dynamically from there at run-time - check out [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-8.0) for the how.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, an application needs to be deployed with all of its dependencies (i.e. dlls). So the simplest solution is to just copy all the files from the build-folder to the target computer.

A somewhat more advanced solution is to create an installer that does all the necessary copying, including creating shortcuts etc. "Visual studio installer project" and "Wix" are two different examples of installer frameworks.

.Net core also support [single file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli). This packages all your dependencies into a single exe-file that can be deployed.

Answer (score -1):

I use an application called **Setup Factory** to create all my setup files. You can deploy any type of files whether they are .dll files or some other files. I guess you are working on a console application where you are importing some nugget package. All you need to do is to create a installer and for this you can use Setup Factory or you can create a **Setup project** inside the solution. That will also let you deploy all those necessary .dll files and make yourself an **installer**. The installer when run, will install all the required files plus the .exe file to specified destination on the disk. If this information was helpful, let me know.